# Why won't my fluid simulation render?

Tags: fluid-simulation

My fluid simulation baked and showed up, but when I rendered it it shoed no simulation. The rendered viewport even shows the fluid! The bottom part of the screen shows the rendered viewport, the top screen shows the images after rendered[image: Look at the top to see the render]

Answer (score 1):

Your object doesn't render because it is disabled for rendering in the outliner.
Use the camera icon to enable.

[image]